# Can I share my water heater outlet with another appliance?

Tags: wiring, water-heater, receptacle, circuit-breaker

I have a water heater point and I would like to piggy a water pump to the same outlet. My country's voltage here is 240V 50/60hz. I prefer not to add new wiring as it very costly.

My water heater is running 3.3kw with 13.8(A) and the power outlet is a 15(A) with a 20(A) circuit breaker. Existing wire is inside the outlet is 2.5mm.

The water pump that I want to install is running 300 watt, the shop mention that it should be less 2(A).

Can I piggyback or add another outlet to this one?

(As second option, the shop mention that I can divert out from the light outlet instead since the water pump has low amperage. Not sure which is a better option.)

---

Sorry that I had missed out an important point on the water heater. It should be instant water heater.
[image]

The location of this heater is in my 2nd floor bathroom and is plug to a receptacle inside the bathroom. The water pump that I want to install is about 3 to 4 meter away just out my bathroom window.

My piggyback mean, I would like to one of:

1. Hard-wire the pump wire directly into my heater's receptacle (unfortunately not to breaker because is too far and existing wires are all hidden inside the concrete walls),
2. Add another receptacle from my existing heater receptacle, or
3. Add another receptacle (similar to point 2) but from my existing lighting point since the pump has low amperage.

Note : whether is hard wiring or adding new receptacle, both will be inside a conduit pvc pipe and running outside the wall. I understand that my heater receptacle is directly hard wire to the breaker with no looping to others. However, for the lighting point mention above, there are other lighting point sharing the same breaker. Both breaker are 20A.

Comment: There should be several places from which to power a water pump which is only 300 W (1.3 A at 230 V). What do you mean by 'piggyback'? Is the water heater plugged into a receptacle or is the water heater 'hard-wired' to a breaker?  Where is the water pump going to be physically located? Will the pump and the power cord to the water pump be outside the wall in a place where is can be visually inspected or will it be inside a wall cavity?

Comment: An electrical engineer once told me that the UK power system is simpler than the US/North American sytem because we standardized first and as other countries electrified they were able to learn from the consequences of some of our choices. From the vantage point of the present day some of our choices were mistakes. One mistake was the 120 V / 240 V duality. Countries with only 230 V residential power have a simpler and better performing electric distribution system with no significant increase in risk of electric shock (especially now with GFCI  ( aka residual current circuit breaker).

Comment: 120/110 was for backward compatibility with Edison's 110DC system. You would not have wanted to mess with 220DC, that is one nasty customer.

Comment: Please [merge your guest and registered accounts](/help/merging-accounts), which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!